# Checking the availability of rooms

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 table in my sql database:

```
Table Room

roomnumber   roomtype    
  1           DeluxeRoom           
  2           DeluxeRoom  
  3           DeluxeRoom
  100         StandardRoom           
  101         StandardRoom  
  102         StandardRoom
```

Room is a table which store the room and their type.

```
Table Reservation

reservationid  checkin       checkout
  1           2017-01-01     2017-01-03
  2           2017-01-10     2017-01-20
  3           2017-02-05     2017-02-08
```

Reservation is a table where users make their booking.

```
Table RoomReserve

reservationid    roomnumber
 1                 1
 2                 100
 2                 101
 3                 1
 3                 2
 3                 3
```

In RoomReserve, for each reservationid, I can input multiple values for roomnumber. I can also input same roomnumber for different reservationid if the checkin and checkout date are not the same.

I am trying to make a query in php to count the available rooms when user want to book rooms but the results i am getting is wrong.

Here are the codes i am trying:

```
 1) $sql="SELECT COUNT(roomnumber) FROM room WHERE roomtype='DeluxeRoom'  AND roomnumber NOT IN ( 
SELECT * FROM roomreserve r,reservation e, room m  WHERE r.reservation_id=e.reservation_id AND m.roomnumber=r.roomnumber
AND ('$checkin' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) OR ('$checkout' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date))"; 

2) $sql="SELECT COUNT(roomnumber) FROM room WHERE roomtype='DeluxeRoom'  AND roomnumber NOT IN ( 
SELECT COUNT(roomnumber) FROM roomreserve r,reservation e, room m  WHERE r.reservation_id=e.reservation_id AND m.roomnumber=r.roomnumber
AND ('$checkin' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date) OR ('$checkout' BETWEEN start_date AND end_date))";
```

Comment: If you dont know the answer then dont flag down the question.

Comment: Try to extend a bit the phrase "_I am trying to make a query in php to..._"

Comment: You need to break down the issue. Is it PHP relevant? Do parts of the query work? Is `BETWEEN` the issue or `reservation_id`? The field names in your query don't match those in your data, and the `SELECT *` doesn't match the `roomnumber NOT IN` clause. Start with a smaller problem and build up from there.

Comment: How do you know which user reserved which room?

Comment: And what if I book 2 rooms, one for me , and one for my friend but my friend is due to arrive a day before me, and leave a day later?

Answer (score -1):

If a customer is currently checked into a room, what do you have in the checkout column? If it's null, then you can use `checkout is null` for your query or modify that part as you deem fit.

```
select count(*) from room where roomtype = 'DeluxeRoom' and roomnumber not in (
select room.roomnumber from room, reservation, roomreserve where room.roomtype = 'DeluxeRoom' and roomreserve.roomnumber = room.roomnumber and roomreserve.reservationid = reservation.reservationid and checkout is null)
```

You might also add a checked_out flag to Reservation table, to make your query easier.

Answer (score -1):

At no point do you say what is wrong with what you have, but assuming the issue is syntactical (ie. you simply can't get the statement to execute), then try this instead:

```
SET @start_date = '2017-01-01';
SET @end_date = '2017-01-10';
SELECT COUNT(roomnumber) FROM room WHERE roomtype='DeluxeRoom'  AND roomnumber NOT IN ( 
SELECT r.roomnumber FROM roomreserve r,reservation e, room m  WHERE r.reservationid=e.reservationid AND m.roomnumber=r.roomnumber
AND ((checkin BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date) OR (checkout BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date)));
```

At least that's a valid SQL statement. Wrap it in PHP as necessary.

Full test case for c&p ease:

```
DROP TABLE Room;
DROP TABLE Reservation;
DROP TABLE RoomReserve;

CREATE TABLE Room (
    roomnumber int,
    roomtype varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO Room
VALUES
    (1, 'DeluxeRoom'),
    (2, 'DeluxeRoom'),
    (3, 'DeluxeRoom'),
    (100, 'StandardRoom'),
    (101, 'StandardRoom'),
    (102, 'StandardRoom');


CREATE TABLE Reservation (
    reservationid int,
    checkin date,
    checkout date
);

INSERT INTO Reservation
VALUES
    (1, '2017-01-01', '2017-01-03'),
    (2, '2017-01-10', '2017-01-20'),
    (3, '2017-02-05', '2017-02-08');

CREATE TABLE RoomReserve (
    reservationid int,
    roomnumber int
);

INSERT INTO RoomReserve
VALUES
    (1, 1),
    (2, 100),
    (2, 101),
    (3, 1),
    (3, 2),
    (3, 3);


SET @start_date = '2017-01-01';
SET @end_date = '2017-01-10';

SELECT COUNT(roomnumber) FROM room WHERE roomtype='DeluxeRoom'  AND roomnumber NOT IN ( 
SELECT r.roomnumber FROM roomreserve r,reservation e, room m  WHERE r.reservationid=e.reservationid AND m.roomnumber=r.roomnumber
AND ((checkin BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date) OR (checkout BETWEEN @start_date AND @end_date)));
```

I get "2" in response, which is the number of DeluxeRoom's which don't have a reservation date between 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-10 (rooms 2 and 3).

Comment: Your logic for date comparison is wrong and overly complicated.

Comment: Did your comment end up in the wrong spot? That's the OP's logic, not mine.

Comment: The op wants to know how to check for room availability so it seems reasonable that a given answer may attempt to address that issue

Comment: Seems you missed the first sentence, "but assuming the issue is syntactical". The required logic is not expressed explicitly enough to address it, meanwhile the logic in the answer does something that could be reasonably expected to be useful, (ie. returns the number of DeluxeRoom's which don't have a reservation date between start_date and end_date). Premature optimisation is the root of all evil, etc.